# Are functions instance in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, instance

I was reading [Kotlin documentation about lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) and came to a line that says

> To call fold  we need to pass it an **instance of the function type** as an
>   argument

And this gave me two main questions.

1. What is an instance of a function ( or a function type)
2. How can functions (function type) have an instance

I was not successful with finding the answer anywhere, please help.

Comment: The page you linked to explains it in great details. Have you read the remaining of the page?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I still don't get why its instance of the function type rather than just type of the function.

Comment: `(a: String) -> Int` is a function type. { it: String -> it.length } is an instance of this function type. The type is what you specify to tell... what the type of an argument or return type is (like `String`, `Int`, or  `(a: String) -> Int`). An instance of a type is a value that has that type, like "hello", 42, or `{  it: String -> it.length }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What is an instance of a function (or a function type)

A function type is described as `(Parameters) -> Result`, an instance of that
would be any function implementing a signature matching that type description.

```
val function: (Int, Int) -> Int = { a, b -> a + b }
```

> 2. How can functions (function type) have an instance

Just like anonymous classes in java, functions can be expressed as objects inline.
For example in java you would have the `Consumer<T>` SAM-Type (single abstract method-type) which only has the `accept(T): void` method. In kotlin that type is `(T) -> Unit` and an instance of this is created using a lambda expression as `var consumer: (T) -> Unit = { println(it) }` or a function reference. The instance then later is invoked through either the invoke operator `consumer(x)` or the invoke function `consumer.invoke(x)`.